# Как считать неизвестное кол-во строк из консоли?

Tags: c#, строки

В консоль поочередно вводятся строки. Как их считать, если не дано их количество.

Comment: Вопрос в другом --- как их перестать считывать? Или это не требуется?

Comment: Да, вопрос как раз в этом, я не правильно сформулировал

Answer (score 4):

Считывать, например, в цикле while, пока не произойдет событие, означающее конце ввода- например, ввод пустой строки или спецкомбинация клавиш.

То же самое ведь делается при чтении текстового файла - читаем, пока не обнаружили EOF

Например, так:

```
string input;

while (input != "exit")
{
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    //некие действия
}
```